# set a delegate for dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController in my app which uses a didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate to monitor whether the user has picked an image.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] is called, it will dismiss the current UIImagePickerController view and go back to the view before the UIImagePicker is displayed. I want to set a delegate to send back the selected image to the previous view when the dismissModalVewControllerAnimated is called. How do I do that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The delegate should be set when you create the picker. Is the controller you're going back to the one that created the picker? If so, it should set itself as the delegate at that time. You should be using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead of the depreciated dismissModalViewController.

Comment: thanks. yes it is going back to the one that has created the picker. I am new to xcode and am not sure how to set a delegate with it. Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: @user1829700, setting the delegate is easy, but the whole process can be a little confusing until you get the hang of it. Basically, you need to add a protocol in the picker, and a delegate property. The controller that's going to be the delegate, just has to do something like picker.delegate = self when it creates the picker. I suggest you read the guide "Working With Protocols" in the Apple documentation.